# The proper way to normalize images for training in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, deep-learning

I want to normalize the images in preprocessing. Now I know two usual ways:

```
# 1. min-max
min_, max_ = tf.reduce_min(image), tf.reduce_max(image)
image = (image - min_) / (max_ - min_) + min_

# standardization
image = tf.image.per_image_standardization(image)
```

However, I still wonder

- if I need to further normalize it within `[-1, 1]` beside the operation above? I read that this mioght be good for training as well.
- from the perspective of generalization, do we really need operations like `per_image_standardization`? I mean, wouldn't the neural networks learn to fit in this kind of environment by themselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to my knowledge using the above methods is kind of rare when it comes to normalizing the image to a certain range, the more common are as such

```py
import tensorflow as tf

image_path = '/path/to/image'
image_byte = tf.io.read_file(image_path)
image = tf.io.decode_jpeg(image_byte)

# Normalize image
img_norm_0_to_1 = tf.cast(image, tf.float32) / 255. # [0 - 1] range
img_norm_neg1_to_1 = (tf.cast(image, tf.float32) / 127.5) - 1.0 # [-1 to 1] range
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I agree with your opinion. Actually, I have been using the same method as you describe, just was not sure if it was correct.